# express route not falling on '/_api/' but instead on '/*'?

Tags: express, react-router

i have this code for production and i have a route with '/_api/...'

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  this.app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy <--- production
  sessionConfig.cookie.secure = true; // serve secure cookies
  //Serve any static files

  this.app.use(
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/build'))
  );
  // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
  this.app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
      path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/build', 'index.html')
    );
  });
}
```

but when i try to go to e.g.: '/_api/tests.js' i am getting the index.html response, how can i make it fall under routes that has underscore '/_api/tests.js' and not on '/*'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express matches routes based on their order in your code. If the wildcard route is before any other routes, and next() isn't called conditionally, any subsequent routes will not be matched. In other words, you need to place your /_api/ route handling before the /* route.